# Python integration within rails app

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a rails app to like photos on instagram for our employees.

Right now it almost works. I built a background process that every 6 seconds will use a cannibalized version of Instabot (just the login and like features) to like a photo from our db.

```
liker_job.rb

def self_perform()
..
if link.present?
  `python lib/python/instaliker.py/go_like.py #{link.media_id}`
  link.update_attribute("liked?", true)
end
```

The `go_like.py` accepts the media_id and sends it to the [Instabot](https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py) like method. The `go_like.py` file is setup almost the same way that Instabot's example.py is with our Instagram login hard written in.

When the script is ran, Instabot logs in to my test account and then likes the first picture in the Instalink db, and then it logs out.

It does this every 6 seconds and it the pictures stop getting actually liked after the 10-30th picture. I am wondering if there is a way to login to my Instagram on the rails application and pass the credentials to Instabot. So that way I can login once and when I run my custom like method from Instabot I will already be logged in.

This is the first time I have worked with python and I have been just piecing things together from the Instabot team.

tldr; I want to know if it's possible to login to Instagram within my rails app and pass the credentials to Instabot.py to go like a picture by media_id.

If I am like < 30 photos I can run this no problem, but I am also concerned that Instagram will see me logging in and out every 6 seconds 200 times.

Comment: You are going way to hard on this. I would definitely not advise you to log in and out every 6 seconds. You go against Instagrams "terms of use" and with an aggressive bot like this you will get blocked immediately.  Instabot? learn proper selenium and do it yourself. The bots on GitHub are on instagrams radar and even if you go easy they will instantly know that everything is fake what you did since they recognize the way the bot operates.

Comment: You can use Capybara to automate selenium - but I would check what is allowed in the terms of use first.

Comment: I initially thought of using Capybara, but was unsure how to like the photos through rails only. I don't use Instagram, this project came out of a bet and so I initially tried to cut corners.

Comment: @hansTheFranz That's the exact reason I want to do this in rails. I am not using it with it logging in every 6 seconds. I broke the project into steps and integrating the Instabot was the last step I finished. And then I thought I wanted to just move the login feature out and it would be fine. I really like the idea of using selenium and liking the photos that way.